# How to setup the default C++ compiler for maven

Tags: maven

When running command maven clean install from my windows pc, I got the following error messages.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.bytedeco:javacpp:0.11:build (process-classes
 on project nd4j-x86: Failed to execute JavaCPP Builder: Cannot run program "cl
: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Suppose I need to get the cl.exe from Visual Studio which I hate to do. I have the MinGW installed in my windows with evn variables setup properly. Is there a way to ask maven call my gcc compiler instead of the cl compiler?

Comment: This isn't Maven, this is JavaCPP. It might work by calling something like `mvn clean install -Dproperties=windows-x86_64-mingw`... Does it?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you've read the Getting Started instructions on Windows and Troubleshooting:

- Windows users may need to install Visual Studio Community 2013 or
  later, which is free. You will need to add its path to your PATH
  environment variable manually. The path will look something like
  this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin

  Type cl into your CMD. You may get a message informing you that
  certain .dll files are missing. Make sure that your VS/IDE folder is
  in the path (see above). If your CMD returns usage info for cl, then
  it’s in the right place.

If you use Visual Studio:

- Set up PATH environment variable to point to \bin\ (for cl.exe etc)
  Also try running vcvars32.bat (also in bin) to set up environment
  before doing mvn clean install on ND4J (it may save you from copying
  headers around) vcvars32 may be temporary, so you might need to run
  it every time you want to do ND4J mvn install (In addition, the
  include path for Java CPP doesn’t always work on Windows. One
  workaround is to take the the header files from the include directory
  of Visual Studio, and put them in the include directory of the Java
  Run-Time Environment (JRE), where Java is installed. This will affect
  files such as standardio.h.)

http://nd4j.org/getstarted.html#windows

And join us on Gitter if you have questions:

gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Comment: Please [do not post an answer that consists essentially of a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important points in your answer; leave the link for extra information or as a reference.